# Python3 - Requests - Iteration - KeyError on second iteration

Tags: python, api, python-requests

**Context / What I'm doing**

Hello, I'm using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to retrieve information from an API. I'm iterating over data in a `.csv` file then sending a request with a constructed url.

I then want to take the `r.json()` and extract a specific piece of information.

I then take that information and run some regex on it to break it up, which I'll then use to construct a new string.

```
with requests.Session() as s:
for i, (event) in enumerate(csv_data, start=1):
    url = 'https://api.someurl.com/datapoint1' + datapoint1+ '/datapoint2/' + str(datapoint2)
    headers = {'key': key, 'secret': secret}

    r = s.get(url, headers = headers)

    content = r.json()
    print(content)
    something = content[u'something']
    print(something)

    data1 = re.findall(r'pattern', something)[0]
    data2 = re.findall(r'pattern', something)[0]

    data_constructed = 'string' + data1+ 'string' + data2 + 'string'
    print(data_constructed)
```

**Problem**

The first iteration runs fine, and I see printed data on the screen, however on the second iteration of the loop, I get a `KeyError`.

```
something = content[u'something']
KeyError: 'something'
```

The weird thing is that if I comment out the regex stuff, all the code works just fine:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
for i, (event) in enumerate(csv_data, start=1):
    url = 'https://api.someurl.com/datapoint1' + datapoint1+ '/datapoint2/' + str(datapoint2)
    headers = {'key': key, 'secret': secret}

    r = s.get(url, headers = headers)

    content = r.json()
    print(content)
    something = content[u'something']
    print(something)

    # data1 = re.findall(r'pattern', something)[0]
    # data2 = re.findall(r'pattern', something)[0]

    # data_constructed = 'string' + data1+ 'string' + data2 + 'string'
    # print(data_constructed)
```

This is driving me nuts, I can't figure out why. I've tried doing `r = None` and `content = None` but that doesn't help. I can't determine why it's doing this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is it possible that the second link doesn't have `something` in content?. `KeyError`s are usually when the key isn't present in a dict

Comment: I've checked the response JSON and the second response and others after do, in fact, have the 'something' key.

Comment: _The weird thing is that if I comment out the regex stuff, all the code works just fine_ I don't see how this is possible.  That code comes after the error location so it can't possibly have any effect.

Comment: I know, right? It's madness! I'm thinking about maybe copying each json dict object to an array, then in a separate loop, running the regex stuff.